# Cannot get metadata (current-total) from state/info of celery task after calling update_state

Tags: django, state, celery, task

I am building a web application with Django. I need to display a progress bar.
To track the progress inside a celery task I am passing an ajax call to the backend containing information needed for the process and another one with a timeout to keep watching for progress of the celery task. I can not understand what I am doing wrong, but I cannot get back the information regarding the information I stored in the 'meta' of the update_state.
Following relevant part of code.

**tasks.py**

```
@shared_task
def myFunction():
    current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'current':0, 'total':100})
    .
    do stuff
    .
    current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'current':25, 'total':100})
    .
    do stuff
    .
    current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'current':50, 'total':100})
    .
    do stuff
    .
    current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'current':75, 'total':100})
    .
    do stuff
    .
    current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'current':100, 'total':100})
    return result
```

**views.py**

```
def view():
    ****GET PART****


    if 'processing' in request.POST:

        result = myFunction.delay()
        request.session['id'] = result.id
        result_out = result.get()
        return JsonResponse()

    elif 'checkstate' in request.POST: 
        proc_id = request.session['id']
        task = AsyncResult(proc_id)
        return JsonResponse({'state':task.state, 'info':task.info})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found the answer. The error was due to the get() method called right after the delay() method. After removing that I was able to get the advancing progress.